# How to display the value in dropdown using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, model-view-controller

i have a dropdown, where i can select AgencyName, with that selected  AgencyName, i tried to display its AgentName  in the next dropdown. But my code does'nt display the AgentName in the next dropdown.

i have my view page like:

```
<span class="LabelNormal">Agency</span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LightAgencies.agencykey, new SelectList(Model.LightAgencies.Agency, "Key", "Value"), "", new {@id = "OwnerAgency" })
<span class="LabelNormal">Agent</span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LightOwnerAgent.au_key, new SelectList(""), "", new {  @id = "OwnerAgent" })
```

And i have my jquery like,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("#OwnerAgency").change(function () {
    var procemessage = "<option value=`0`> Please wait...</option>";
    $("#OwnerAgent").html(procemessage).show();
    var url = "/Index/GetOwnerAgent/";
    // Get agency key
    var OwnerAgency = $("#OwnerAgency :selected").val();
    // Get agent
    var OwnerAgent = $("#OwnerAgent :selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { agencykey: OwnerAgency },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var OwnerAgent = $("#OwnerAgent :selected").val();
            alert(OwnerAgent);
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
});
```

where my controller  "/Index/GetOwnerAgent/" giving the exact value for OwnerAgent. As iam the beginner i dont know how to do this, Kindly tell me.

Comment: Why are you using backticks (`) instead of quotes? in  value=``0``

Comment: @Kavitha P. what you want to do with this Ajax call ?

Comment: @ Frebin Francis -i called the method  "/Index/GetOwnerAgent/" to get OwnerAgent value(au.key,agentname).

Comment: i want to display the agentname in the "Agent" dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you display the selected value in the dropdownlist as soon as the controller responds. I think you want to select the result from the controller in the dropdown.
Assuming that the data returned from the controller is a value that exists in the dropdownlist, you should be able to use:

```
...
    success: function (data) {
                $("#OwnerAgent").val(data);
            }
...
```

Comment: Do you see the alert box when you run your existing code?